# .net: Introducing anonymous types in business layer?

Tags: .net, anonymous-types, business-logic-layer, presentation-layer

I don't want to create a new class and decided to use anonymous type in order to send data from presentation layer to biz layer.

But my problem is how can I introduce an anonymous type in biz layer?  I use Vb.Net 2008 and VS 2008.

**EDIT**

Actually, I have to work with some data that their nature are really temporary classes and I won't use them again in my own project .

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why are anonymous types the answer?

Comment: I don't want to create new classes so use anonymouse types instead. But they are not introduced in business logic layer.  This is the problem

Comment: Cross assembly or even cross function use of anonymous types is *very* restricted. I don't think they are the answer to your problem.

Comment: Why don't you want to add a new type/class? Not choosing the obvious way needs a very good reason.

Comment: @0xA3: well, data I am working on are not the main They are produced in an intermediate proccess.

Answer (score 2):

[Anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)  are scoped so that they can be accessed in a strongly typed way only inside the method in which they were created. If you want to pass them from method to another, you'll have to resort to passing them as `object` and using reflection (or `dynamic`) to access their properties, which most certainly isn't what you want.

Use a proper class for your data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't, don't!

If they are living in acorss server boundaries you end up using `dynamic` on the client of your function which is no good.

This is because you would probably have to expose the object as `object` in the method signature and you will loose all the benefits of type safety.

On the other hand, you are not achieving anything, compiler spits out a class for you anyway.

Comment: Could you please explain it more?

Comment: I have added a bit more explanation. If you put a code snippet of what you want to do, I can explain a bit more.

Comment: Well, I have a winform that handles master-detail data. There are 2 datagridviews that their data are as details. So, when user clicks on "Save" button, in addition to saving master data, I should save all datail data i.e. 2 datagridviews data.  I decided to create 2 anonymous types for 2 datagridviews and send it as 2 parameters of Save method. But the problem is buisiness logic layer doesn't know any thing about anonumous types. what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recomment you make such things. Such code won't be maintainable. But you could use `dynamic` from 4.0, that is no good for this.

Comment: @odiseh: Then I suggest you switch to C# 4.0 ASAP